# What to use in Production environment instead of UserSecrets

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a console app in dotnet core. I use appsettings.Development.josn and appsettings.Staging.json for dev and staging environment but for the production environment i use the UserSecrets. I have two problem when the app is running on production env it does not create UserSecrets in the %Appdata%/Microsoft so I have to make it manually and then it starts to work.

Another part of my question is this: 
today I  found out that microsoft wrote [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets)

> The Secret Manager tool is used only in development. You can safeguard Azure test and production secrets with the Microsoft Azure Key Vault configuration provider. See Azure Key Vault configuration provider for more information.

I dont have Azure. What can I use in production if I am not supposed to use the UserSecrets.

Comment: environment variables

Comment: I think you are right I have to use the Environment variables.

Comment: https://12factor.net/config elaborates on why environment variables are the answer

Answer (score 4):

While environment variables are one of the most used options in web development and  [The Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/) documents [states](https://12factor.net/config): "Store config in the environment" there are some reasons why this may not be the best approach:

- the environment is implicitly available to the process and it's hard to track access. As a result, for example, you may face with situation when your error report will contain your secrets
- The whole environment is passed down to child processes (if not explicitly filtered). So your secret keys are implicitly made available to any 3rd-party tools that may be used.

All this are one of the reasons why products like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/use-cases.html) become popular nowadays.

---

So, yes, you may use environment variables, but be aware)

Answer (score 0):

For storing secure data in your app, if you're using Azure, So Azure KeyValut is your answer, you can see [Azure Microsoft Azure Key Valut](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/),

In case you're using K8S, you can store it on CSI driver

Or system OS environment variables

Comment: What if I create a console-app which is being run from a scheduled task ... since this is an On-Premises environment Key Vault might not be the first thing that would come to my mind.